# How to attach visual studio workflow 2013 to content type

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2013

I am creating visual studio workflow 2013, I am able to attach it with list, but I want to attach workflow with content type.

Please suggest me, how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike previous versions, SharePoint 2013 does not support workflows that are scoped to a content type.

You can check detailed description here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163181(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163181%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4a62ca48-05a4-4114-879a-88ebd3750804/create-an-approval-workflow-for-content-types-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio-2012?forum=sharepointdevelopment